# Sniffer capture files in network traffic

Tags: assembly, memory-management, dll-injection, network-traffic, sniffer

I have a program that downloads a dll file from the server and then injects it into an X process.

My goal is to capture that dll file, try to capture incoming packets, I managed to capture packets (TCP) with Wireshark but I don't know how to proceed as the packets are fragmented into almost 6000 packets and each packet contains network headers (https)

Is there a technique or method that allows me to capture the dll file?

- I recommend that you continue with the path of catching the DLL through network traffic
- or once the dll has been injected into process X, try to capture it from the process memory (in that case what techniques would you use).

Comment: IIRC, Wireshark can combine the payloads of all the packets from one TCP stream into a single large stream.  Load your capture in Wireshark and check the menus.

Comment: depending on what the https request is/are, it may be possible to simply use that url to download the file.

Comment: As Peter said, Wireshark can recombine packets, filter them and even show conversational flow. However, debugging the program is also viable. One API you could watch out is `InternetReadFile` or even the lower level `recv`. Finally, [any.run](https://any.run) can show you the connections (with data) made by a program. Though TLS may be a problem, that should, at least, help with taking a decision :)

Comment: hi @Peter Cordes how do you get the url to download the file from captured packages

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted; that makes the captured data not very useful.  I forgot about that when writing my first comment since you were talking about recovering the DLL from network traffic.  You can see what host it's talking to, but even the URL is only sent over the encrypted channel.

Comment: As you know, the IMGUI function is used to obtain data from a process in real time. Is there a way to capture the code of that imgui within the memory stack of said process?